# System volume speaker icon always appears when using MPVolumeView

Tags: iphone, ios, mpvolumeview

I have sort of the reverse problem expressed here [in this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297176/how-do-i-turn-the-system-volume-overlay-back-on-after-using-mpvolumeview)

In my case, I (iPhone 4.3 GM) and a tester (iPhone 4.3.1) are seeing the behavior that when we adjust the volume with our finger on the MPVolumeView or with the physical volume switches, the speaker volume overlay is always appearing (see screenshot).
[image: screenshot of speaker overlay on top of MPVolumeView]

Here is the code where I create the MPVolumeView. I think it is totally generic and standard:

```
    MPVolumeView *volumeView = [[[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:volumeSlider.bounds] autorelease];
[volumeSlider addSubview:volumeView];
```

*volumeSlider is simply an outlet to a plain UIView that I put on in IB.

The one other thing I can think of is that in IB, the volumeView view is checked as hidden. Then I unhide it when my audio starts playing (it is an audio streaming app).

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845222/iphone-sdk-how-to-disable-the-volume-indicator-view-if-the-hardware-buttons-are

Comment: Thank you. Related, but not a solution for me. They are trying to hide the slider I believe.

Comment: OK by doing some hacking I found a solution. First, I unchecked "hidden" in IB. Just by doing this, the overlay stayed away. But I still wanted to hide the MPVolumeView when no sound is playing. So I put a setHidden:YES message in my -viewDidLoad method, but then the overlay came back! So I had to have a timer set for .01 in the future call a method that hid the MPVolumeView. Apparently Apple is checking a bit after the view becomes visible to see if there is a visible MPVolumeView and if you hide it too fast, then Apple never sees it. Weird.

Comment: Dammit, this didn't fix it after all, I'm still seeing the issue.

Comment: Paul, did you ever find a solution to this as I am having the same problem with iOS 5?

Comment: Nope, the problem is still there and I have no more ideas on how to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Take UIView in xib and bind with IBOutlet MPVolumeView.

I know this post is old,but if anyone wants this answer.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to suppress the overlay while using the device volume buttons, simply move the frame of the MPVolumeView off the screen. The overlay will not appear.

Comment: Not useful. I want the slider (the MPVolumeView). I don't want the overlay.